# Add img src to input button

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to add img src to input button by using this code:

```html
<input type="submit" 
   value="<?php echo strtoupper($addhouse);?>" 
   id="sbAddHouse"
   name="sbAddHouse"
   img src="./1.png style="width:140px;"
   onclick="window.location.href='#here';">
```

can't see the img src="./1.png ..
any help please?

Comment: You can't do that. That's not how HTML works. You'll need to use `<button>` if you want to insert an image inside or work with `background-image`.

Comment: what do you really want to do with that image.? Are you trying to use thumbnail?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `background` - shorthand property or `background-image` property - the easy way.

Or

You can use a `span` or `div` with absolute or relative positioning property. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position for an extensive reference.

`img` is a tag and you cannot use a tag inside a tag.

Thanks